# Removing invalid rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the following csv file:

```
name,age
here is a random line right here
tom,40
julia,
brandon,20
```

And to load it into a dataframe:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('example.txt')

                               name   age
0  here is a random line right here   NaN
1                               tom  40.0
2                             julia   NaN
3                           brandon  20.0
```

Line 0 has a `NaN`, but so does Line 2 (which is legitimate -- it's an optional field). Is there any way to determine this in pandas so as to exclude the bad row? The closest I can think of is:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('example.txt').dropna()
      name   age
1      tom  40.0
3  brandon  20.0
```

Which incorrectly gets rid of line 2.

Comment: Prefilter the csv to remove the undesirable line(s).

Comment: How do you define `bad row`? Need to have some logic for that.

Comment: I agree with previous comment. You need to define a condition to define what a 'bad row' is. If you decide to remove the `bad rows` after reading it in to pandas, you can use the drop method `new_df = df.drop(df[<some condition>].index)`

Comment: @najeem could you think of an example condition for the above that would work?

Comment: @JohnMee so the filtering of "bad data" should happen before it even goes into Pandas? I was hoping that I could do it within panda...

Comment: @DavidL condition could be `df.mycol.str.strip().str.split().apply(len) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` there is no way to know that line 0 was "incorrect" but line 2 was "correct". Supposing you are using `,` only as the separator, you can make a python script to strip off the lines that doesn't have a `,` in your csv.

A quick way to do this is using `sed -n '/,/p' example.txt > filtered_example.txt`, this will create a file `filetered_example.txt` without the undesired lines.